# Typescript - .at is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I developed a backend using NestJS + Typescript. I accessed the element of array using `.at` function. It works fine in my own computer. However, when I deployed into my staging server, it gets error `.at is not a function`. How to fix this?

Comment: might the browser you are checking is not updated and it does not support it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error might be due to different Node.js versions on your computer and the computer on which deployed. And since `at' is relatively a new addition in` js`, the` Node.js` on the deployment/staging server may not be supporting it.
The options you have are:-

1. Upgrade the `Node.js` on the deployment/staging server to to a version that supports `ECMAScript` features, including the .`at()` function.
2. Avoid Using .at() Function by using traditional array indexing methods to access elements. For example,
   Instead of using:-

`const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; const element = myArray.at(1); // This may cause an error in older Node.js versions`

Use this approach:-

```
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const element = myArray[1]; // Accessing the element using array by indexing
```

Hope this works for you